# OS X: How can I copy the shell path to clipboard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, shell, clipboard

When working with files on my mac I employ a mixed approach of shell/finder or keyboard/mouse, similar to working with 4NT and Explorer on Windows.

One thing I use(d) extensively on Windows is to copy the path of the current directory to the clipboard. This is an extended feature of [TakeCommand by JPSoft, on Windows](http://jpsoft.com/).

Is there a way to copy the current path from the bash shell to the mac's clipboard, so I can use it in 'file open' and/or similar dialogues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf "$PWD" | pbcopy
```

There's also the program `pbpaste` that pastes (`pb` = `pasteboard`, i.e. clipboard).

---

Use `Cmd-Shift-G` in open file dialogs to insert that path.

---

<sup>Thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/users/310/dennis-williamson) for the `printf` hint.</sup>

Comment: `printf "$PWD" | pbcopy` or `printf "$(pwd)" | pbcopy` will eliminate the trailing newline.